# Pasar datos entre actividades en andorid

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en la que se pueden visualizar pdf. El problema es que tengo una actividad en la que muestro el pdf a la cual le paso el pdf en base64 para que pueda mostrarlo, pero al pasarle un pdf que es mas grande de la cuenta me salta este error

> `!!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1315208)`

En esta línea de código

```
val intent = Intent(applicationContext, PdfViewActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("pdfbase64", pdfItem.contenidoPDF)
        startActivity(intent)
```

¿Hay alguna propiedad o configuración con la que no haya "límite" al pasar datos entre activities mediante un intent?

Comment: Puedes guardar el archivo temporalmente en el almacenamiento del teléfono y abrirlo en el otro activity

Comment: Yas he conseguido solucionalo he encontrado por internet que el tamaño maximo era menos de 1mb por lo que he decido crear una clase statica con un solo atributo el cual serña la cadena que queria pasar anteriormente. Al esa clase ser visible desde el resto de clases puedo acceder a la cadena sin problemas. Gracias

Comment: Ponlo como respuesta a tu pregunta con un breve ejemplo de como hacerlo. Otros podrán ver tu solución y recibirás rep adicional por los votos positivos. Puedes aceptar tu propia respuesta unas horas después de registrarla!

Comment: Ya tienes la respuesta por si le quieres echar un ojo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ver explico mi situación. Yo estaba haciendo una aplicacion con la que descargabas un pdf de internet y conseguias una cadena en base64 con su contenido. Este contenido lo pasabas a otra activity qeu seria la encargada de mostrar el pdf en pantalla. Todo esto funcionaba hasta que intoduje un pdf demasiado grande y el contenido que pasaba entre activities era demasiado grande. Leí por distintos sitios eso de guardarlo en un archivo etc, pero decidí hacer lo siguiente. Cree una clase con un solo atributo llamado contenido y que fuera accesible desde todas las clases.

```
object LinkData {
    var contenido: String = ""
}
```

Al descargar el pdf de internet y conseguir su contenido en base64 se lo asignaba al atributo de esta clase.

```
{ pdfItem ->
            val intent = Intent(applicationContext, PdfViewActivity::class.java)
            LinkData.contenido = pdfItem.contenidoPDF
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

Ahora nos iriamos a la clase donde se visualiza el pdf y recogeriamos el contenido del atriburto en vez del getExtraString()

```
val base64String = LinkData.contenido

        // Decodifica el string Base64 a un ByteArray
        val decodedBytes = Base64.decode(base64String, Base64.DEFAULT)

        // Carga el ByteArray en el PDFView
        bind.pdfView.fromBytes(decodedBytes)
            .defaultPage(0)
            .enableSwipe(true)
            .swipeHorizontal(false)
            .onPageError { page, t ->
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error al cargar la página $page", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            .load()
```

Y así es como he conseguido acceder a ese dato sin crear ficheros u otras cosas.

Gracias por la ayuda‍

Comment: En una página web se entiende que aunque los archivos incrustados terminen pesando aproximadamente un 50% más, es más rápido cargar la página con un menor número de peticiones al servidor. No creo que esté sea tu caso así que me pregunto por qué prefieres codificarlo en base64 antes que usar los bytes crudos del archivo.

Comment: Me parecía mas sencillo trabajar con un string que con un array de bytes. Yo también lo pensé pero ya tenía mi base de datos con la columna de tipo string y ya lo tenia bastante avanzadillo. Asi que como tampoco me molestaba tenerlo en string y asi lo decidi en el principio lo deje así

Answer (score 1):

El error :

> !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size =
> 1315208)

indica que la transacción que tratas de realizar falló, ya que tratas de enviar demasiada información la cual no es soportada.

Te sugiero revisar:

**[La transacción de Binder falló porque era demasiado grande TransactionTooLargeException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException)**

> La transacción de Binder falló porque era demasiado grande.

> Durante una llamada de procedimiento remoto, los argumentos y el valor
> de retorno de la llamada se transfieren como objetos Parcel
> almacenados en el búfer de transacciones de Binder. Si los argumentos
> o el valor devuelto son demasiado grandes para caber en el búfer de
> transacciones, la llamada fallará. TransactionTooLargeException se
> lanza como una heurística cuando una transacción es grande y falla, ya
> que estas son las transacciones que tienen más probabilidades de
> desbordar el búfer de transacciones.

**La opción en este caso es enviar la url o la ruta del PDF en tu dispositivo a tu Activity,  ya en la activity destino abres el PDF, evita enviar la información del  PDF en Base64** .

```
val intent = Intent(applicationContext, PdfViewActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("uriPdfbase64", uriPDF)
        startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias al final encontré otra solución que he dejado abajo por si le quieres echar un vistazo